# IDEA Omni code suggestion

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, pycharm, webstorm

Is it possible to have omni code suggestion?

For example:

[image]

In picture up, I want to have suggestion for **checkModelValues** word...

---

Update: Showing my settings:

[image]

Comment: You want completion inside the string? Try `Code | Completion | Cyclic Expand Word (Backward)`

Comment: @LazyOne I don't have this in my pycharm IDE ? :( ...  see the update question...

Comment: No -- not in settings. Look in main menu. That's the action to use (like `Ctrl+Space` for "normal" code completion)

Comment: @LazyOne Thanx mate, I would not do this without you! Put the comment to the answere and I will accept it as a valid answere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try `Main Menu | Code | Completion | Cyclic Expand Word (Backward)` for such completion in strings. This action will search for words *above/before* caret position and will offer it one-by-one (i.e. next invocation will show next word).

**P.S.**
Ordinary `Cyclic Expand Word` action will offer words that located below/after caret position.